# Do I need to call NotifyPropertyChange() in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In my program I would like to disable a `contentPresenter` when my other `contentPresenter` gets focus. Each presenter is represented by a property located in my `MainWindowViewModel`. This is also where the `IsEnabled` property is located for both presenters.

Both `contentPresenters` are created with the following structure: UserControl -> ViewModel -> Data Model.

Right now I am trying to disable the necessary `contentPresenter` by changing the `IsEnabled` property in the main window's ViewModel from the code-behind of the `contentPresenter` that gets focus.

`contentPresenter` User Control code-behind:

```
public partial class EditBlockUC : UserControl
{
    public EditBlockViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as EditBlockViewModel; } }

    public EditBlockUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Runs when the user control gets focus
    private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This UserControl has access to MainWindowViewModel through
        //it's own ViewModel, EditBlockViewModel         
        ViewModel.MainViewModel.LeftWidgetEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

The line: `ViewModel.MainViewModel.LeftWidgetEnabled = false;` successfully changes the property in the Main window's view model, but the view is not affected. Can I fix this by finding a way to call `NotifyPropertyChange()`? If so, how would I do that?

If this is the completely wrong solution please let me know, and help me fix it.

Thank you

**Update 1:**

My complete base class:

```
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChange<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)property;

        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        }
        else
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;

        OnPropertyChanged(memberExpression.Member.Name);
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

My `LeftWidgetEnabled` property:

```
public bool LeftWidgetEnabled
{
    get { return _leftWidgetEnabled; }
    set { SetField(ref _leftWidgetEnabled, value, "LeftWidgetEnabled"); }
}
```

Comment: are you reaching the getter of LeftWidgetEnabled after SetField ?
Please post your LeftWidgetEnabled property .

Comment: I just set a breakpoint at `get` in my `LeftWidgetEnabled` property, and the program never stopped at it.

Comment: that means that your PropertyChanged event was never raised 
post the base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and SetField method.

Comment: have you debugged this and checked if Property Change is not null 
and that the correct property name is given ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LeftWidgetEnabled` of your `ViewModel.MainViewModel` class must be like this:

```
private bool leftWidgetEnabled;
public bool LeftWidgetEnabled
{
    get { return leftWidgetEnabled; }
    set { SetField(ref leftWidgetEnabled, value, "LeftWidgetEnabled"); }
}
```

Also, your `MainViewModel` must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You're better off letting the `MainViewModel` inherit from a `ViewModelBase` and let `ViewModelBase` implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{        
    private bool leftWidgetEnabled;
    public bool LeftWidgetEnabled
    {
        get { return leftWidgetEnabled; }
        set { SetField(ref leftWidgetEnabled, value, "LeftWidgetEnabled"); }
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // boiler-plate
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

Your ContentPresenter should then be bound like:

```
<ContentPresenter IsEnabled="{Binding Path=LeftWidgetEnabled}" />
```

while the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` (where the `ContentPresenter` is on) should be an instance of `MainViewModel`.

For instance:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="MyApplication.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:viewModels="**PATH TO YOUR VIEWMODELS-ASSEMBLY**"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

    <ContentPresenter IsEnabled="{Binding Path=LeftWidgetEnabled}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I've made the changes to the property and added SetFieldMethod to my `PropertyChangedBase` class. However, the property is set to `false`, but the view still doesn't change. I will update my question with the `SetField` method that I am using.

Comment: Is it a problem if I am setting LeftWidgetEnabled to `true` by default? I can also say that I have exactly what you have in my `ViewModelBase` class

Comment: No, a default setting shouldn't affect this. Do you have your `LeftWidgetEnabled` property actually bound to your control? I've edited my code.

Comment: I have bound my `LeftWidgetEnabled` property to my `contentPresenter` like you have above. When I run the program, in the output window it now says that it can't find the property. It appears to be looking for it in the ViewModel of the `contentPresenter` that is to be disabled.

Comment: That's why you need to set the `DataContext` of your UserControl. Look above.

Comment: What if the `DataContext` of that control is already that of it's own ViewModel?

Comment: You need to specifically set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to your MainViewModel. Not the `DataContext` of your `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40571/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-setoy)

Answer (score 0):

You implement INotifyPropertyChanged as below

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  private bool leftWidgetEnabled;
  public bool LeftWidgetEnabled
  {
     get 
      { 
        return leftWidgetEnabled;
      }
      set 
      { 
          leftWidgetEnabled=value
         OnPropertyChanged("LeftWidgetEnabled"); 
      }
   }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```